# How to upload a file to SharePoint with jQuery from a remote location

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, file-upload, client

I have been search for a day now but I haven't been able to find anything useful...I'm starting to wonder if it is even possible.

I'm building an Adobe Air app that needs to send a file to Sharepoint through it's basic webservices. This app may be run on machines outside of any sort of Active Directory or Domain so I expect that I also need to authenticate to Sharepoint. But I can test as an admin on the server so authentication is not a problem yet.

I'm just trying to focus on getting the file uploaded/attached

Comment: You would use $.ajax and send the file as a POST. Are you uploading it via a form? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: A mashup of Adobe Air, jQuery and SharePoint sounds...not like a fun project. (well, the jQuery part would be fun. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you exact question is, but note that sharepoint has different authentication options. It's typically set up as part of Active Directory.

Comment: You're rightabout the NO FUN part. I didn't think of it eigther...rather upload to PHP.

Comment: @Seth: do you happen to know which SharePoint Service accepts a post??

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't upload files to sharepoint unless you have permission to do so (ie as an authenticated user with the proper rights), or if you are using rwep (run with elevated privileges). The latter is dangerous. What step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Check this out http://martinezdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/07/sharepoint-drag-and-drop-file-uploads.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my jQuery library called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com). The Web Service you want is Lists, and probably UpdateListItems. I've never tried to upload documents using jQuery, but that's where you want to look.

Comment: Is SPServices intended to run within SharePoint or from remote apps that want to connect with SharePoint?

Comment: Edward: SPServices is designed to work within a SharePoint environment, as it uses the current context for much of its configuration decisions. However, SharePoint's Web Services are exposed for use elsewhere. M.